# Android Studio- Rendering Problems: can't find Drawer Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I've been facing this problem for a few days now. Android studio is not able to render the DrawerLayout.

I found a few similar questions online but none of the solution worked for me.

I'm using **Android Studio 1.2.1.1** with **Gradle 1.2.3**

I've tried changing the build tools to 22, 21, 19. Noting worked for me.

How can I make it work? If it's a bug, is there a workaround ?

[image]
[image]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.MainScreenActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/facebook_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_empty_72" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="No Polls"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/polls_swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/facebook_background">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/polls_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_poll" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate
        android:id="@+id/fetchingDataProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/submitMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:fab_colorNormal="#1E88E5"
        app:fab_colorPressed="#0065BE"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_18dp" />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#1E272C"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_profileView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/nav_drawer_background_orange" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_profileImage"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_guy_blue"
            app:border_color="@color/white"
            app:border_width="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_userName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/navigation_drawer_profileImage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="UserName"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_userLevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/navigation_drawer_userName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="PickupNoob"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#55000000"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="MY PROFILE"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_item_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_item_background"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_nav_login"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="LOGIN / SIGNUP"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_item_about"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_item_background"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_nav_about"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="ABOUT"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_item_donate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_item_background"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_nav_donate"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="DONATE"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_item_rate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_item_background"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_nav_rate"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="RATE THE APP"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_item_feedback"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_item_background"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_nav_feedback"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="FEEDBACK"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_item_logout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_item_background"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_nav_logout"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="LOGOUT"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your android version on your designer preview , which is render your xml.[image]

Comment: It's working for normal views.
Just not working for support v4 widget. I tried with all the versions but not working with any of them.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with the layout xml code. BTW could you specify your android studio version, gradle version, Buildtool version etc. Also could be because of system image. Which system image are you using for rendering ?